# How to watch entire directory of scss and compile files separately in their own sub-folders?

Tags: css, sass, node-sass, gulp-sass, dart-sass

I have a css folder with sub-folders populated with scss files. How can I watch the whole folder and automatically generate a separate style.css file on change for every folder.

```
`--css
    --content
      content.scss
    --home
      home.scss
    --about
      about.scss
    --main
      main.scss`
```

If I change, say, content.scss I want it to generate content.css, and idealy, content.min.css.

Well. I tried to use Dart-sass, but it generates *.css.map and I need *.min.css.
Dart-sass doesn't reflect to changes made in imported files like `@import '../file.scss'`.
I tried to use `concurrently`, but it takes a lot of space in `package.json`, looks dirty and it failed every time I ran it.
I have no idea how to do it with node-sass.
I looked at some solutions, but most of them seem to be really old and outdated , they are all about old technologies.

Comment: Nodemon is a perfect candidate for this scenario. Nodemon can watch a directory of files and execute any arbitrary command whenever any file changes. It might look something like `nodemon --exec "node-sass build && node-sass minify" ./css/**/*.scss`. Note: you will need to update the command to invoke node-sass with the correct arguments.

Comment: @RyanWheale gonna give it a chance

Comment: Do I need NodeJS for this?

Comment: Yes you will need node. You are already using node by using node-sass, gulp, concurrently, and node package manager (npm).